# loopback.js: resend verification email

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

We know in loopback.js, built-in model `User` has method to send a verification email which called by `User.verify`. However, if I want to resend a verification email, does `User` has its own strategy or I have to write it by myself?

Comment: did you mean that Lookback has provided the built in support for the resend verification mail or not?

Comment: Yes, I wonder whether loopback has provided that feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah loopback provides the feature. Documentation:
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Registering+users#Registeringusers-Verifyingemailaddresses

Source code in github : 
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management/blob/master/common/models/user.js